# Re-format table, placing multiple column headers as rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of fishing catches, showing number of fish and total kg, for all the fishing days. Current format of the data is showing as below

[image: Table 1]

In the other reference table is a list of all the official fish species with codes and names.

[image: Table 2]

How can I re-format the first table so the rows are repeated for each day showing a certain species with the corresponding total catches and kgs in a row. So instead of the species kg and n having their different columns, I would have them in rows while there is only one n and kg column.  I am thinking of looping through the list of all species and based on the numbers it will duplicate the rows in a way with the right values of n and kg of the species in the rows. This is the final format I need. My database is SQL Server.

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: My guess is you need a `JOIN` and `UNION` maybe. The problem is that you are storing your data badly. You shouldn't have separate columns for each fish type, you should have a foreign key reference.

Comment: There is no way to render the `Species` column using your reference table other than through dynamic SQL.  Really, you should generally not be trying to do something like this.  Just fix your data model to the tall format and move on.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Problem this is not my data, I received it this way so I am trying to come up with a cleaner format

Comment: I will give a simple union query below, but ideally you should fix your data or keep it in tall format moving forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a union query here:

```sql
SELECT Day, 'Albacore' AS Species, ALB_n AS n, ALB_kg AS kg FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Day, 'Big eye tuna', BET_n, BET_kg FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Day, 'Sword fish', SWO_n, SWO_kg FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Day, Species;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `cross apply` here, e.g.:

```sql
/*
 * Data setup...
 */
create table dbo.Source (
  Day int,
  ALB_n int,
  ALB_kg int,
  BET_n int,
  BET_kg int,
  SWO_n int,
  SWO_kg int
);
insert dbo.Source (Day, ALB_n, ALB_kg, BET_n, BET_kg, SWO_n, SWO_kg) values
  (1, 10, 120, 4, 60, 2, 55),
  (2, 15, 170, 8, 100, 1, 30);
create table dbo.Species (
  Sp_id int,
  Sp_name nvarchar(20)
);
insert dbo.Species (Sp_id, Sp_name) values
  (1, N'Albacore'),
  (2, N'Big eye tuna'),
  (3, N'Sword fish');
/*
 * Unpivot data using cross apply...
 */
select Day, Sp_name as Species, n, kg
from dbo.Source
cross apply dbo.Species
cross apply (
  select
    case
      when Sp_name=N'Albacore' then ALB_n
      when Sp_name=N'Big eye tuna' then BET_n
      when Sp_name=N'Sword fish' then SWO_n
    else null end as n,
    case
      when Sp_name=N'Albacore' then ALB_kg
      when Sp_name=N'Big eye tuna' then BET_kg
      when Sp_name=N'Sword fish' then SWO_kg
    else null end as kg
) unpivotted (n, kg);
```